# I need help obfuscating my Java project

Tags: java, obfuscation

So, I've searched through all of the Q&As on here but every answer I got was how to obfuscate a .jar file. The thing is, I don't know how to convert my project INTO a jar file. Anyone care to link me to anything that will help me?

Comment: In Eclipse, you can make a runnable jar via Export -> Runnable JAR File -> you have a JAR.

Comment: an alternative to doing this in the IDE is simply having ant build your project and create your jar file for you - you can google for this

Answer (score 3):

You can find plenty of documentation and tutorials over the internet.
Below you find the first search hits using **Google**. Give it a chance and use Google on your own.

- If you're using the *Eclipse IDE* have a look [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm).
- If you're using *NetBenas IDE* have a look [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html).
- If you're using *IntelliJ IDEA IDE* have a look [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/packaging-a-module-into-a-jar-file.html).
- If you're using *Ant* have a look [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076208/java-app-dev/automate-your-build-process-using-java-and-ant.html).
- If you're using the command line have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: Generally if you're just going to refer OP elsewhere, you should post the links as a comment. Answers should be able to stand of their own, regardless of whether there is a link.

Comment: @user3580294 In genera I agree but this question is so broad and has been answered a Thousand times .. why inventing the wheel again?

Comment: Cheers. I really needed this. I will admit I kind of feel dumb for not figuring this out using my common sense.

Comment: So perhaps post a link to a duplicate? Or direct OP to those links in the comments?